# Selenium | How to differentiate between two ids which are same

Tags: selenium

On a external website I am trying to click the save button. But a cancel button has the same class.

```
buttonSave = browser.find_element_by_class_name("_spectrum-Button_7a745")
buttonSave.click()
```

HTML :

```
<button class="_spectrum-Button_7a745 _spectrum-Button--secondary_7a745 _spectrum-ButtonGroup-Button_25328" type="button" data-testid="cancel-button">
  <span class="_spectrum-Button-label_7a745">Cancel</span>
</button>
<span class="_spectrum-Button-label_7a745">Cancel</span>

<button class="_spectrum-Button_7a745 _spectrum-Button--cta_7a745 _spectrum-ButtonGroup-Button_25328" type="button" data-testid="cta-button">
  <span class="_spectrum-Button-label_7a745">Save</span>
</button>
<span class="_spectrum-Button-label_7a745">Save</span>
```

Comment: I've inserted linebreaks in your HTML code - are you sure that there are two of the same labels for each button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can apply `text based xpath`.

```
//span[text()='Save']/parent::button
```

There are basically two save text on the HTML that you've shared. So, when we just write text based xpath which is `//span[text()='Save']` we still will be left out with two nodes. so to further distinguish, we have to use parent node which is a button so, that is the reason we are using  `parent::button`

**PS:** text based xpath should only be used when the Automation Engineer knows, the website is going to be in a particular language. in this case for e.g. English.

Also in case you are looking for `css_selector`, the below should get the job done.

```
button[data-testid='cta-button']
```

**Code using xpath :**

```
buttonSave = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Save']/parent::button")
buttonSave.click()
```

**Code using css_selector :**

```
buttonSave = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-testid='cta-button']")
buttonSave.click()
```